# Scrolling not working on dynamically added items to jQuery mobile list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am adding jQuery mobile list items dynamically using jQuery ajax response object. But the scrolling on page is not working properly.

The AJAX success function is:

```
success: function(response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) 
    {
        $('#client_list').append('<li class="client_details"><a href="#client_sites" data-transition="slide">' +response[i] + '</a></li>');
    }
    $('#client_list').listview('refresh');
}
```

Here, `client_list` is the `id` of `ul`.

Comment: Something fishy here `(response)[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer, but so late.

I used a jquery mobile panel inside a `<div data-role="page">`. So, the scrolling is not working properly.

After removal of panel, Scrolling in page working efficiently.